# How to sorting list interface

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I am having problem with sorting patient list based on seriousness and arrival time. Can take a look what wrong with my code? See the LList.java, the SortPatient method is correct?

ListInterface.java

```
public interface ListInterface<T> {

public boolean add(T newEntry);

public boolean add(int newPosition, T newEntry);

public T remove(int givenPosition);

public void clear();

public boolean replace(int givenPosition, T newEntry);

public T getEntry(int givenPosition);

public boolean contains(T anEntry);

public int getLength();

public boolean isEmpty();

public boolean isFull();

public int getPosition(T anObject);

public void SortPatient(ListInterface<Patient> patientList);
}
```

Llist.java

```
import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.Comparator;

import java.util.Date;


public class LList<T> implements ListInterface<T> {

private Node firstNode; // reference to first node
private int length;     // number of entries in list

public LList() {
    clear();
}

public LList(T[] arr) {
    clear();
    firstNode = new Node(arr[0], null);
    Node p = firstNode;
    for (int index = 1; index < arr.length; index++) {
        p.next = new Node(arr[index], null);
        p = p.next;
        //index must start with 0
        //or add(arr[index]);
    }
    length = arr.length;

}

public int getPosition(T anObject) {
    Node currentNode = firstNode;
    int position = 0;
    while (currentNode != null) {
        position++;
        if (currentNode.data.equals(anObject)) {
            return position;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    return -1;
}

public final void clear() {
    firstNode = null;
    length = 0;
}

public boolean add(T newEntry) {
    Node newNode = new Node(newEntry);
    // create the new node

    if (isEmpty()) // if empty list
    {
        firstNode = newNode;
    } else {                        // add to end of nonempty list
        Node currentNode = firstNode;                   // traverse linked list with p pointing to the current node
        while (currentNode.next != null) {      // while have not reached the last node
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        currentNode.next = newNode; // make last node reference new node
    }

    length++;
    return true;
}

public boolean add(int newPosition, T newEntry) { // OutOfMemoryError possible
    boolean isSuccessful = true;

    if ((newPosition >= 1) && (newPosition <= length + 1)) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newEntry);

        if (isEmpty() || (newPosition == 1)) {     // case 1: add to beginning of list
            newNode.next = firstNode;
            firstNode = newNode;
        } else {                                                      // case 2: list is not empty and newPosition > 1
            Node nodeBefore = firstNode;
            for (int i = 1; i < newPosition - 1; ++i) {
                nodeBefore = nodeBefore.next;       // advance nodeBefore to its next node
            }

            newNode.next = nodeBefore.next; // make new node point to current node at newPosition
            nodeBefore.next = newNode;      // make the node before point to the new node
        }

        length++;
    } else {
        isSuccessful = false;
    }

    return isSuccessful;
}

public T remove(int givenPosition) {
    T result = null;                 // return value

    if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= length)) {
        if (givenPosition == 1) {      // case 1: remove first entry
            result = firstNode.data;     // save entry to be removed
            firstNode = firstNode.next;
        } else {                         // case 2: givenPosition > 1
            Node nodeBefore = firstNode;
            for (int i = 1; i < givenPosition - 1; ++i) {
                nodeBefore = nodeBefore.next;       // advance nodeBefore to its next node
            }
            result = nodeBefore.next.data;  // save entry to be removed
            nodeBefore.next = nodeBefore.next.next; // make node before point to node after the
        }                                                               // one to be deleted (to disconnect node from chain)

        length--;
    }

    return result;                   // return removed entry, or
    // null if operation fails
}

public boolean replace(int givenPosition, T newEntry) {
    boolean isSuccessful = true;

    if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= length)) {
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        for (int i = 0; i < givenPosition - 1; ++i) {
            // System.out.println("Trace| currentNode.data = " + currentNode.data + "\t, i = " + i);
            currentNode = currentNode.next;     // advance currentNode to next node
        }
        currentNode.data = newEntry;    // currentNode is pointing to the node at givenPosition
    } else {
        isSuccessful = false;
    }

    return isSuccessful;
}

public T getEntry(int givenPosition) {
    T result = null;

    if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= length)) {
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        for (int i = 0; i < givenPosition - 1; ++i) {
            currentNode = currentNode.next;     // advance currentNode to next node
        }
        result = currentNode.data;  // currentNode is pointing to the node at givenPosition
    }

    return result;
}

public boolean contains(T anEntry) {
    boolean found = false;
    Node currentNode = firstNode;

    while (!found && (currentNode != null)) {
        if (anEntry.equals(currentNode.data)) {
            found = true;
        } else {
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
    }

    return found;
}

public int getLength() {
    return length;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    boolean result;

    if (length == 0) {
        result = true;
    } else {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return false;
}

public String toString() {
    String outputStr = "";
    Node currentNode = firstNode;
    while (currentNode != null) {
        outputStr += currentNode.data;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return outputStr;
}

private class Node {

    private T data;
    private Node next;

    private Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    private Node(T data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
} // end Node

public void SortPatient(ListInterface<Patient> patientList) {
    if (patientList == null) {
        return;
    }

    boolean swapped;
    Patient patient;

    do {
        swapped = false;
        patient = head;
        while (patientList.next != null) {
            if (patient.compareTo(patientList.next) < 1) {
                swap(patientList.current, patientList.next);
                swapped = true;
            }
            patient = patientList.next;
        }
    } while (swapped);

}

}
```

Patient.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.T;

public class Patient implements Comparable<Patient> {

String patientId;
String patientName;
String patientGender;
String patientIcNumber;
String patientContactNumber;
Date date;
int seriousness;
static int count = 0;

public Patient() {
}

public Patient(String patientId, String patientName, String patientGender, String patientIcNumber, String patientContactNumber, Date date, int seriousness) {
    this.patientId = patientId;
    this.patientName = patientName;
    this.patientGender = patientGender;
    this.patientIcNumber = patientIcNumber;
    this.patientContactNumber = patientContactNumber;
    this.date = date;
    this.seriousness = seriousness;
    count++;

}

public String getPatientId() {
    return patientId;
}

public void setPatientId(String patientId) {
    this.patientId = patientId;
}

public String getPatientName() {
    return patientName;
}

public void setPatientName(String patientName) {
    this.patientName = patientName;
}

public String getPatientGender() {
    return patientGender;
}

public void setPatientGender(String patientGender) {
    this.patientGender = patientGender;
}

public String getPatientIcNumber() {
    return patientIcNumber;
}

public void setPatientIcNumber(String patientIcNumber) {
    this.patientIcNumber = patientIcNumber;
}

public String getPatientContactNumber() {
    return patientContactNumber;
}

public void setPatientContactNumber(String patientContactNumber) {
    this.patientContactNumber = patientContactNumber;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public int getSeriousness() {
    return seriousness;
}

public void setSeriousness(int seriousness) {
    this.seriousness = seriousness;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return patientId + "  " + patientName + "  " + patientGender + "  " + patientIcNumber + "  " + patientContactNumber + "  " + date + "  " + seriousness + "\n";
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Patient t) {
    int patientSeriouness = t.seriousness;
    Date arrival = t.date;
    if (this.seriousness == patientSeriouness) {
        return this.date.compareTo(arrival);
    } else {
        return Integer.compare(this.seriousness, patientSeriouness);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues in your code (I just went through add,getentry and sort method):

- In getEntry method, Remember index always start with 0 and go after till length - 1, so you should change our method to:

  ```
  public T getEntry(int givenPosition) {
  T result = null;

  if ((givenPosition >= 0) && (givenPosition < length)) {
      Node currentNode = firstNode;
      for (int i = 0; i < givenPosition; ++i) {
          currentNode = currentNode.next;     // advance currentNode to next node
      }
      result = currentNode.data;  // currentNode is pointing to the node at givenPosition
  }
  return result;
  }
  ```
- Change your interface and class implementation to remove passing on the ListInterface reference and your implementation should look like:

  ```
  public void SortPatient() {
  if (firstNode == null) {
      return;
  }

  boolean swapped;
  Node patient;

  do {
      swapped = false;
      patient = firstNode;
      while (patient.next != null) {
          if (patient.data.compareTo(patient.next.data) > 0) {
              swap(patient, patient.next);
              swapped = true;
          }
          patient = patient.next;
      }
  } while (swapped);
  }


  private void swap(Node patient, Node nextPatient) {
      T temp = patient.data;
      patient.data = nextPatient.data;
      nextPatient.data = temp;
  }
  ```
- Your compare to method in Patient class needs some improvements and it should be as below:

  ```
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Patient t) {
      int patientSeriouness = t.seriousness;
      Date arrival = t.date;
      if (this.seriousness == patientSeriouness) {
          return this.date.compareTo(arrival);
      } else {
          return ((Integer)this.seriousness).compareTo(patientSeriouness);
      }
  }
  ```
- Last but not the least, your class definition LList should take generics of type Comparable (As you are using compareTo method), so you need to mandate that and it should be defined as

  ```
  public class LList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements ListInterface<T>
  ```

Comment: I followed your instruction but the swap symbol cannot be found,  swap(patient, patient.next);

Comment: Apologies i missed it! Edited the answer and thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Glad my post helped you.

Comment: The sorting u write is bubble sort with big O(n^2)?

Comment: I said it before in your last post, you have the idea now so you could modify. Btw its not really original bubble sort but modified (improved) version of bubble sort.